# Javascript -Automatically loop through and execute functions in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

I am trying to loop through and execute the functions in my array however i am having trouble doing so, here is the code:

```
<p id="demo" >I will change colour automatically.</p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var array_of_functions = [
  function first_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
  },
  function second_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "blue";
  },
  function third_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
  },
  function forth_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "white";
  }
];
var time = 1000;

function change(){
for(var i=0, len=array_of_functions.length; i < len; i++){
}

window.onload = change;
</script>
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong.)

Comment: You're looping through the array but you aren't doing anything inside the `for` block on each iteration... what did you think would happen? Try putting in a statement that executes the function

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the functions inside the loop using `array_of_functions[i]()`, but if you want to put a delay between each iteration you will need to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

In modern JavaScript, you can use `async` and `await` to maintain the imperative style of your code. Since each of the functions in your array are almost identical, you can change the array so that it only stores what changes: the color.

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function change() {
  for (const color of ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'white']) {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.color = color;
    await delay(1000);
  }
}

window.onload = change;
```

```html
<p id="demo">I will change colour automatically.</p>
```

Comment: Nice approach. Wish I would have thought of using the colors directly in the loop first.

Answer (score 0):

You never execute your functions inside the `for` loop. Change

```
for(var i=0, len=array_of_functions.length; i < len; i++){
}
```

to:

```
for(var i=0, len=array_of_functions.length; i < len; i++){
    array_of_functions[i]();
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a time delay of 1000ms in between each call (as indicated by the variable `time`), you can chain promises together using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const array_of_functions = [
  'red', 'blue', 'green', 'white'
].map(function (color) {
  return function () {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.color = color;
  };
});

var time = 1000;

function sleep(ms) {
  return function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  };
}

function change() {
  array_of_functions.reduce(function (promise, func) {
    return promise.then(sleep(time)).then(func);
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

window.onload = change;
```

```html
<p id="demo">I will change colour automatically.</p>
```

Using ES6 arrow functions, you can simplify it to this:

```js
const array_of_functions = [
  'red', 'blue', 'green', 'white'
].map(
  color => () => document.getElementById('demo').style.color = color
);

const time = 1000;

const sleep = ms => () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});

function change() {
  array_of_functions.reduce(
    (promise, func) => promise.then(sleep(time)).then(func),
    Promise.resolve()
  );
}

window.onload = change;
```

```html
<p id="demo">I will change colour automatically.</p>
```

Finally, using ES2017 `async` / `await`, you can further simplify it:

```js
const array_of_functions = [
  'red', 'blue', 'green', 'white'
].map(
  color => () => document.getElementById('demo').style.color = color
);

const time = 1000;

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});

async function change() {
  for (const func of array_of_functions) {
    await sleep(time);
    func();
  }
}

window.onload = change;
```

```html
<p id="demo">I will change colour automatically.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 0;
var array_of_functions = [
  function first_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
  },
  function second_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "blue";
  },
  function third_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
  },
  function forth_function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "brown";
  }
];
var time = 1000;

function change(){
  for(var i=0, len=array_of_functions.length; i < len; i++){
    array_of_functions[i]();
  }
}
window.onload = change;
```

```html
<p id="demo">I will change colour automatically.</p>
```

```
for(var i=0, len=array_of_functions.length; i < len; i++){
}
```

to:

```
for(var i=0, len=array_of_functions.length; i < len; i++){
    array_of_functions[i]();
}
```

Comment: The last change you suggest is incorrect. Doing so will evaluate `change` immediately.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you're really trying to do this:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, htm, M, I, S, Q, rand, old = onload; // for use on other pages
onload = function(){ // load not indented to save space
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
rand = function(array){
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange', 'aqua'];
var demo = I('demo'), dS = demo.style;
setInterval(function(){
  dS.color = rand(colors);
}, 300);
} // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#fff; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#demo{
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <p id='demo'>I will change color automatically.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Change the `colors` Array and interval as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```js
var i = 0;
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var array_of_colors = ["red","blue","green","white"];
var time = 1000;

window.onload = function(){
   setInterval(function(){
      demo.style.color = array_of_colors[i++%4];
   }, time)
};
```

```html
<p id="demo" >I will change colour automatically.</p>
```